# Magento 2 checkout new field is excluded from post data

Tags: magento2, checkout, post-data

I have this module for add newsletter subscription to checkout page in a Magento 2 project. I have added a checkbox field by following code:

**app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php**

```
namespace Muaw\Subscription\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;


class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['subscribe'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'subscribe'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.subscribe',
            'label' => 'Opt-In to our news letter',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 250,
            'id' => 'subscribe',
            'value'=>'subscription'
        ];

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

**app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
            <plugin name="subscription" type="Muaw\Subscription\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

Rendered output:

[image: Output]

My problem is when I try to get the order data it does not added into post data

Post data:

[image: Post data]

Did I do anything wrong? Is there any other way to register this field and get post data? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the below files.

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="save-in-quote" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="subscribe" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Model/Checkout/ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout;

class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{

    protected $quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $subscribe = $extAttributes->getSubscribe();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        //$quote->setSubscribe($subscribe );
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'Vendor_Module/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
        }
    }
};
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js**

copy and paste the `Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js` file above given path and modified `payload` method as given below.

```
payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes:{
                            account_no: $('[name="account_no"]').val(),
                            subscribe: $('[name="subscribe"]').val()
                        }

                    }

                };
```

see my below pic it's came you can save it on quote table as given `shippinginformationmanagementplufin.php` file method.

[image]

feel free to ask if you have any queries.

Comment: I have added above files and it gives me an error:
`Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSubscribe() on null in /blahblah/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Checkout/ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php:35`
This is line 35:
`$subscribe = $extAttributes->getSubscribe();`

Comment: @JanakaDombawela have you added `Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml` xml ,  `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` and `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js` file?

Comment: yes they are in the correct path.

Comment: @JanakaDombawela, then execute `php bin/magento cache:clean`, `php bin/magento cache:flush` and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` commands in your `CLI` and try again

Comment: still same error. :( :(

Comment: do you think  the two files in the question `app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php` and `app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/etc/frontend/di.xml` conflicting with newly added files?

Comment: @JanakaDombawela the above error will come when could not find `etc/extension_attributes.xml` file and `extension_attributes:{
                            subscribe: $('[name="subscribe"]').val()
                        }` line of code could not found from `default.js` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39267/discussion-between-janaka-dombawela-and-magento-two).

Comment: @JanakaDombawela, have you got checkbox value?

Comment: Yes. Can you please check the chat?

Comment: @JanakaDombawela, I'm not getting value. where I did a mistake? is anything change my above code or no change?

Comment: @JanakaDombawela, any update?

Comment: I have changed the code. I'll add the code in few minutes.

Comment: I have edited following code: 
**app/codeVendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js** 
`extension_attributes: {
    account_no: jQuery('[name="account_no"]').val(),
    subscribe: jQuery('[name="subscribe"]').val()
}`

Comment: @JanakaDombawela It's returning `on` value even I'm not selected field. Have you tried both **select** and **deselect**?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the return type hint for `\Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface::getExtensionAttributes()` it explicitly states that the return value might be null.
According to other examples in the core, the "right thing to do" seems to be to inject an ShippingInformationExtensionFactory.

Then use something like

```
$extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes() ?: $this->extensionAttributesFactory->create();
```

Answer (score -1):

I used Bojjaiah's solution but I had to change a few things to make it work with Magento 2.2.3.

> default.js, change extension_attributes to:

```
extension_attributes: {
                        email: $('#customer-email').val(),
                        subscribe: Boolean($('[name="subscribe"]').attr('checked'))
                    }
```

In default.js you also need to add jQuery to the define or else you get an error on $.

If you happen to use Magento 2.2.3. delete the following line:

```
 payloadExtender(payload);
```

> In the ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php change the beforeSafeAddressInformation function to this:

```
    /**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
 * @param $cartId
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
 */
public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
) {
    $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
    $email = $extAttributes->getEmail();
    $subscribe = $extAttributes->getSubscribe();

    if($subscribe === true){
        $subscriber = $this->subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
        if ($subscriber->getId() && $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED) {
        } else {
            $status = $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
        }
    }
}
```

> extension_attributes.xml, change this file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
    <attribute code="email" type="string" />
    <attribute code="subscribe" type="boolean" />
</extension_attributes>
</config>
```